# Como montar na página dados recebidos via get

Tags: javascript

Tenho esta linha que é uma parte do código que estou usando para enviar os dados pela URL:

```
<a href="curso.html?id=' + item.id +'&descriacao=' + item.descricao + '" 
    class="a-item">'+ item.nome +'</a></div>
```

Está passando normalmente.

Tenho o código que captura os dados da url na outra página:

```
  var query = location.search.slice(1);
  var partes = query.split('&');
  var data = {};

  partes.forEach(function (parte) {
  var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
  var chave = chaveValor[0];
  var valor = chaveValor[1];
  data[chave] = valor;
  });
```

Agora como faço para inserir esses dados na view?
Estou usando js puro.

Comment: quero pegar os dados da url e inserir em tags, tipo <p>

Comment: Não imagino como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie elementos no seu documento e defina o textContent para eles.

```
<!-- Dentro do body -->
<script>
   (function() {
      var listEl = document.createElement('ul');
      var idEl = document.createElement('li');
      var descricaoEl = document.createElement('li');

      idEl.textContent = data.id;
      descricaoEl.textContent = data.descricao; 

      document.body.appendChild(listEl);
      listEl.appendChild(idEl);
      listEl.appendChild(descricaoEl);
   })();
</script>
```